# VBA script not compatible with Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Excel spreadsheet/workbook that parses through some data and creates another condensed spreadsheet.  The problem is when the sheet has more than 255 columns.  When the line of VBA code at the bottom is run, it returns 1, rather than 258.  It seems as though the VBA script that I am working on is made for the older version of Excel, right? What do I have to do to get this to work properly?

`Excel.Worksheet.Cells(1, MySheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column returns 1 when there are more than 255 columns`

Comment: The problem might be that `Excel.Worksheet.Cells` and `MySheet.Columns.Count` actually refer to different worksheets.  It should probably read: `MySheet.Cells(1, MySheet.Columns.Count).....`

Comment: That should always return column number for the last no empty cell in that row...

Comment: You got is Stewbob, thanks man!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `Excel.Worksheet.Cells` refers to the current, or active, worksheet, while `MySheet.Columns.Count` refers to a specific worksheet, defined in the `MySheet` variable.

If `MySheet` is not the current sheet, this code will return results that may differ from what you expect.

Change the line of code to:

```
MySheet.Cells(1, MySheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, you are absolutely correct.  I appreciate the quick and accurate answer!!